# How to get byte array of each ZipFile entry from ZipInputStream

Tags: android, arrays, unzip

I have a byte array that its contents is filled from a zip file.I want to get each files in that zip archive as a separate byte array in memory to access them randomly. I don't want to write anything in sdcard and keep the arrays in memory.

I've searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793781/how-to-get-bytes-contents-of-each-zipfile-entry-from-zipinputstream-without-writ). Here is my code:

```
protected Map<String,ZipFile> ZipDic;

class ZipFile{
    public byte[] contents;
    public String name;
    public long  size;
}


public makeDictionary(byte[] zipFileArray) {
    try {
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(zipFileArray);
        ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(is);
        ZipDic = new HashMap<>();
        ZipEntry ze = null;

        while ((ze = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            ZipFile zf=new ZipFile();
            zf.name="/testepub/"+ze.getName();
            zf.size=ze.getSize();
            try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int n;
                while ((n = is.read(buf, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                    output.write(buf, 0, n);
                }
                zf.contents=output.toByteArray();
            }catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                zf.contents=null;
            }
            ZipDic.put(zf.name,zf);
        }

    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

my problem is when the `while` loop does the first loop, `zf.contents` is a byte array that its size is alittle less than `zipFileArray` and in the second loop gets exception :

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: CRC mismatch.
```

How can I get each files in `zipFileArray` separately as uncompressed byte arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
while ((n = is.read(buf, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
    output.write(buf, 0, n);
}
```

into

```
while ((n = zipInputStream.read(buf, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
    output.write(buf, 0, n);
}
```